# Mudar formato de data no Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Estou fazendo postagens em um site desenvolvido em Wordpress, o que acontece é que o formato de data está o americano:

```
<span class="published">set 29th, 2016</span>
```

Eu tentei mudar nas opções do Wordpress, indo em **Configurações** > **Geral** e colocando *F j, Y* que é o nosso padrão, porém não surte efeito. Na verdade, o nome do mês, está ok, devido a tradução do tema, porém o tema insiste em colocar o *th*.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/pt-br:Formatando_Data_e_Hora

Comment: @StillBuggin eu fiz conforme o codex, inclusive mencionei isso em minha pergunta.

Comment: Provavelmente este formato de data está fixo no seu tema. Tente ir até a pasta do tema e abrir o template da página que está exibindo esta data.